# Getting the last day of the current month IFNULL in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have an `end_date` column that I need to map, the problem is that it has some null values and I would like to have the last day of the month in case it's null.

This is what I've been trying but for some reason it doesn't allow me to:

```
IFNULL(CAST(end_date) AS STRING, LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), month))
```

What am I might be doing wrong?

Comment: what type is **end_date** ?  and **CAST(end_date AS STRING)** is right syntax. lastly, **IFNULL()** should have same type of parameters.  In your query first and second parameter is  string and date type respectively.

Comment: @Jaytiger end_date is DATE type, I used the right syntax and now it gives me another error message that I think I can solve casting the other date as a string too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> @Jaytiger end_date is DATE type,

Below is more concise one if you want the result as **DATE** type, I guess.

```sql
IFNULL(DATE(end_date), LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), month))
```

Example:

```sql
SELECT IFNULL(DATE '2022-08-26', LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), month)) not_null,
       IFNULL(NULL, LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), month)) `null`,
```

[image]

Comment: That was my very first attempt, but it didn't allow me to use IFNULL with dates

Comment: Not sure how your first query made an error, but it should work. kindly check the example in my updated answer.

Comment: I just tried it (copy-pasting your query) and received this error message:
`
[2022-08-25, 16:15:41 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:93} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1618 for task aggregate_insights_day (400 No matching signature for function IFNULL for argument types: TIMESTAMP, DATE. Supported signature: IFNULL(ANY, ANY) at [141:243]
`
It might have to do with the fact that I'm using Airflow to run this query in BigQuery (the error is referencing an airflow script)?

Comment: seems **end_date** is **TIMESTAMP** type, not **DATE**.  then use **IFNULL(DATE(end_date), LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), month))**.  I've update the query above

Comment: Yes, it worked. Weird, the table I was taking this from was supposed to be DATE type.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it, I was using the CAST syntax wrong and I also needed to CAST the last day of the current month as a string too so I could use the IFNULL.

This is how the correct query would look like:

```
DATE(
    IFNULL(
        CAST(end_date AS STRING),
        CAST(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE(), month) AS STRING)
    )
)
```